# Need to calculate dynamic cumulative sum divided by max cohort per filter in Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

One of my goals was to find average user play days. For example, I need to measure how many days a player plays (number of logins that day) in 60 days (retention day). When a user joins the game that day, I need to count those users and divide them into their cohort per retention day. The following query calculates this.

```
WITH player_details AS (
               SELECT
                   app,
                   channel,
                   uid,
                   install_dt
               FROM users
               WHERE engaged AND NOT cheater
     ),
     player_daily_stats AS (
                   SELECT
                   app,
                   channel,
                   uid,
                   dt,
                   FROM users_daily
               ),
     aggregated_data AS (
                SELECT
                p.channel,
                install_dt,
                s.dt AS dt,
                DATE_DIFF(s.dt, install_dt, DAY) AS retention_day,
                COUNTIF(install_dt = s.dt AND DATE_DIFF(s.dt, install_dt, DAY) = 0) AS installs,
                COUNTIF(s.dt = install_dt + DATE_DIFF(s.dt, install_dt, DAY)) AS retained_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT s.uid) AS active_days
                
                FROM player_details p
                     LEFT JOIN player_daily_stats s ON p.app = s.app AND p.channel = s.channel AND p.uid = s.uid
                WHERE install_dt = '2023-09-01'
                GROUP BY
                p.channel,
                install_dt,
                s.dt
            )
SELECT
    channel,
    install_dt,
    dt,
    retention_day,
    installs,
    retained_users,
    active_days,
    SUM(active_days) OVER (PARTITION BY install_dt, channel ORDER BY retention_day) AS sum_active_days,
    FIRST_VALUE(retained_users) OVER (PARTITION BY install_dt, channel ORDER BY retention_day) AS first_cohort_size,
    SUM(active_days) OVER (PARTITION BY install_dt, channel ORDER BY retention_day) / FIRST_VALUE(retained_users) OVER (PARTITION BY install_dt, channel ORDER BY retention_day)  ratio
FROM aggregated_data
```

Thus the ratio calculates the cumulative retained users and divides by the number of cohorts:

| platform | install_dt | dt | retention_day | installs | retained_users | active_days | sum_active_days | first_cohort_size | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-01 | 0 | 5459 | 5459 | 5459 | 5459 | 5459 | 1 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-02 | 1 | 0 | 2108 | 2108 | 7567 | 5459 | 1.38615131 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-03 | 2 | 0 | 1404 | 1404 | 8971 | 5459 | 1.643341271 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-04 | 3 | 0 | 984 | 984 | 9955 | 5459 | 1.823594065 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-05 | 4 | 0 | 852 | 852 | 10807 | 5459 | 1.979666606 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-06 | 5 | 0 | 727 | 727 | 11534 | 5459 | 2.11284118 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-07 | 6 | 0 | 658 | 658 | 12192 | 5459 | 2.233376076 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-08 | 7 | 0 | 638 | 638 | 12830 | 5459 | 2.350247298 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-09 | 8 | 0 | 616 | 616 | 13446 | 5459 | 2.463088478 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-10 | 9 | 0 | 552 | 552 | 13998 | 5459 | 2.564205899 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-11 | 10 | 0 | 495 | 495 | 14493 | 5459 | 2.654881846 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-12 | 11 | 0 | 481 | 481 | 14974 | 5459 | 2.742993222 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-13 | 12 | 0 | 477 | 477 | 15451 | 5459 | 2.830371863 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-14 | 13 | 0 | 436 | 436 | 15887 | 5459 | 2.910239971 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-15 | 14 | 0 | 447 | 447 | 16334 | 5459 | 2.992123099 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-16 | 15 | 0 | 431 | 431 | 16765 | 5459 | 3.071075289 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-17 | 16 | 0 | 398 | 398 | 17163 | 5459 | 3.143982414 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-18 | 17 | 0 | 358 | 358 | 17521 | 5459 | 3.209562191 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-19 | 18 | 0 | 360 | 360 | 17881 | 5459 | 3.275508335 |
| ANDROID | 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-20 | 19 | 0 | 343 | 343 | 18224 | 5459 | 3.338340355 |

But now I have an extra goal to find user average play days between certain retention day.
So an example I need to find user average play days between retention_day 3 to 7 and for this I need to calculate cumulative retained_users from retention_day 3 and divide cohort retention_day 3 (or max retention day after retention_day 3)

The result should be 3859/984 from the example data

Can I do in Tableau?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **yes**. I put this together with a combination of window_sum, parameter start and end days and some calculated fields.

**Parameter setup:**

[image: p_retention_day_start]

[image: p_retention_day_end]

### Filter to your selected retained day range

Create a calculated field named `_show_retention_range`

> [Retention Day] >= [p_retention_day_start]
> AND [Retention Day] <= [p_retention_day_end]

### Your Numerator (3859)##

Create a window sum function to calculate the retained users within your `retention_day` range.
I named it `_window_sum_retained_users`

> WINDOW_SUM(SUM([Retained Users]))

### Your Denominator (984)

Create a `FIXED{}` calc and call it `_fixed_cohort_start_retained_users`

> IF [Retention Day] = [p_retention_day_start] THEN
> { FIXED [Retention Day] : SUM([Retained Users]) }
> END

### Calculated field to create the final value

> [_window_sum_retained_users] / SUM([_fixed_cohort_start_retained_users])

create a worksheet and arrange the elements like this:

[image: final worksheet]

Hope this helps!